# Why QEMU refuses to run this eabi (bare metal) ARM binary?

Tags: arm, emulation, trace, qemu, execution

I need to get a trace of the machine instructions executed by a bare metal application. I use a STM32 Discovery board for my project, which uses a Cortex-M4 and ARMv7. I want to use QEMU, but it doesn't support my specific board, so I tried:

```
qemu-system-arm -M ast1030-evb -cpu cortex-m4 -m 128M -nographic -kernel build/setup_heap_lab.bin
```

where `build/setup_heap_lab.bin` is the compiled binary (which usually I flash on the board), and `ast1030-evb` is the virtual machine. Note that QEMU seems to support only these Cortex-M4 machines:

```
[alessandro@commodoroII setup_heap_lab]$ qemu-system-arm -M help | grep -i m4
ast1030-evb          Aspeed AST1030 MiniBMC (Cortex-M4)
mps2-an386           ARM MPS2 with AN386 FPGA image for Cortex-M4
netduinoplus2        Netduino Plus 2 Machine (Cortex-M4)
olimex-stm32-h405    Olimex STM32-H405 (Cortex-M4)
```

When I launch QEMU however I get this:

```
[alessandro@commodoroII setup_heap_lab]$ qemu-system-arm -M ast1030-evb -cpu cortex-m4 -m 128M -nographic -kernel build/setup_heap_lab.bin
qemu-system-arm: ../qemu-8.0.2/target/arm/cpu.h:2396: arm_is_secure_below_el3: Assertion `!arm_feature(env, ARM_FEATURE_M)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**Why it is failing?** I kinda found out it has to do with the cpu execution levels, but how can I make it run nevertheless?

Thanks!

Comment: I just need to trace the specific sequence of binary instructions that get executed. That actually doesn't require the machine to match (just the ISA), but I need to profile the goodness of code produced by a compiler, so I think in the end it would be best to simulate the exact code that gets produced

Comment: The "goodness" refers to power consumption and is actually computed from the trace, so it's not relevant here. I just need to trace how many times each instruction gets executed in, say, 1s. But what do you mean with "not an STM32"? Isn't the STM32 the emulated machine?

Comment: qemu cannot tell you anything related to seconds it does not and cannot accurately emulate the chip to that level. you can easily write your own tool to analyze code paths vs using qemu, but also cannot measure time. you are making some assumption about power relative to the instruction which again....you cant get from qemu nor your own trace tool. nor from an tables/documents from arm. That is all well out of the realm of stackoverflow anyway. –

Comment: as far as the specific error message, if that is the point of the question, asked and answered.

Comment: It's probable I am not expert enough to grasp the details, but just so that you know what I'm talking about, I do use an actual board, where I take measures using a multimeter. I need QEMU just to recreate the trace of instructions executed in a test suite, which is more comfortable than using JTAG. Then, I'll cross the power results with the prediction obtained from the trace.

Comment: point is you cannot predict anything from the trace.  the processor is not the bulk of your power nor is it the bulk of the time, pipelined, stm32 has that flash cache thing.  the flash does suck down power that you can see in the st datasheet.  to get a proper trace vs time you have to have access to the source code to the chip and a cycle accurate sim.  qemu cant possibly do that nor anyone else, to truly do that you need access to nda protected ip that you couldnt talk about nor share.   the processor is only a fraction of the power consumption, leds or I/O will dominate.

Comment: You are right, and I am aware of that, but my research currently is to estimate power differences between two equivalent versions of the same program (due to difference in compiler optimizations). We specifically de-soldered the LED so that it doesn't drain energy, and we assume that ceteris paribus we can estimate a difference in the power consumption of the two versions. Of course, I'm not getting a real estimation of the power drained, I need to profile which one of the two versions is more efficient.

Comment: are you running from sram with the flash turned off?  not sure you are going to be able to measure based on this instruction vs that, but optimization ideally fewer instructions per task so a smaller number of clocks, and definitely the thumb extensions will help with that.  as you know.  I dabbled with their low powered parts for a while there purely on solar without a battery (like most "solar" calculators, clocks, etc (they have a battery, you are just extending its life)).  the inrush power on power on was the killer for me with these parts.

Comment: have fun, hope it works out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That assert is a bug in QEMU (https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/issues/1658) which is fixed upstream. The fix will be in the upcoming 8.1 release, and will probably be in a newer 8.0.x stable release if we do another one.

However, you've probably only run into it because your guest code is crashing (it happens on the "raise an exception" codepath). You're trying to run a bare metal binary for board X on a model of board Y, and in general this doesn't work, because the binary is likely to try to access devices or RAM which don't exist on the board model you're running it on. You need to either use a machine model that matches the binary, or else build the binary for the machine model you're using.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, changing the machine to `netduinoplus2` solved the problem. From the QEMU docs: "The STM32F4 series is based on ARM Cortex-M4F core. This series is pin-to-pin compatible with STM32F2 series. The following machines are based on this chip :

    netduinoplus2 Netduino Plus 2 board with STM32F405RGT6 microcontroller" Note that my board is actually an STM32F**407**, but apparently it is compatible.

Comment: I gotta be completely honest, I don't know exactly what you are referring to, since my project uses that board just as a convenient driver (we do not need to exploit the particularities of the board, we just need to run ARM code in the most isolated way possible). Anyway I think I found part of the problem you predicted, because one of the calls of the project (to set the clock) ends up in an infinite loop. Since my goal is to get a trace of the "main" code, I can simply comment that out for now.

Comment: Addition: I suppose the reason QEMU doesn't support well those machines is that there's little point in emulating real hardware (especially for embedded purposes), since the features you'd be normally interested in are not available in an emulated environment?

Comment: The main reason we don't support those boards is that there are hundreds and hundreds of different Arm board types, and we can't support them all.